# Why do I only get values for this year by choosing a data range from the last year? How do I manipulate a data ranges?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

Consider:

```
select AccountingDate
from Test_Plaza_ProductionReport
where AccountingDate >='2015/06/24' AND AccountingDate <= '2016/06/24 23:59:59.999'
    And My Accounting Date only in 2016, whats with 2015?
```

[image]

Comment: I cant reproduce the issue. what is the type of AccountingDate column?

Comment: You were right. Thank you

Comment: Tip: Using external images is frowned upon. If they disappear then your question won't help future users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they're further down in your result set? Alternatively, try searching for values in year 2015:

```
SELECT AccountingDate 
FROM Test_Plaza_ProductionReport 
WHERE AccountingDate >='2015/06/24' AND AccountingDate < '2016/01/01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: My dates was as string, so I had to CAST it to a DATETIME

Answer (score 0):

That is how it should be

```
select AccountingDate 
from Test_Plaza_ProductionReport 
where AccountingDate <= CAST('2016/06/24' AS DATETIME) 
  AND AccountingDate >= CAST('2015/06/24' AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep dates in the proper format

```
Select AccountingDate 
 From  Test_Plaza_ProductionReport 
 Where AccountingDate between '2015-06-24' AND '2016-06-25' and AccountingDate<'2016-06-25'
 Order By AccountingDate
```